# Получение имени пользователя по его ID (discord python)

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

У меня есть айди пользователя и следующий код:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!") 

@bot.command() 
async def getuser(ctx, userid: int): 
 user = bot.get_user(userid)
 await ctx.send(user.name)
```

Этот код должен на команду `!getuser [ID]` отправить никнейм пользователя, чей айди указан.
Но вместо этого появляется ошибка в консоли:

```
Ignoring exception in command getuser:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/z_japan_bot/give2.py", line 103, in getuser
    user = bot.get_user(userid).name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Comment: почему вы не хотите  discord.Member использовать? он как раз для таких целей и предназначен.Под ваш вопрос, попробуйте: bot.get_user(int(тутид))

Comment: ```bot.get_user(int(тутид))``` не работает. Если отправить такое сообщение, то выходит ошибка в консоли о том, что нельзя отправить пустое сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `bot.get_user(id)` используйте `await bot.fetch_user(id)`.